# Android -- View Over Media Player

Tags: android, media-player, overlay

I wanted to build an application that will allow user to share comments about any video while they watch them. For that I require a View over the Media Player view.

Can anyone please guide me how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout and stack the View you want over the MediaPlayer View.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am a new bee in Android development, can you post an example or sample code